# Config parsing with awk

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, awk, curly-braces

I am trying to learn some awk magic and I am trying to parse data according to these rules:

If the allow-service section contains default, https:any, all, ssh:any, ssh:tcp I wish to output the interface name and the matched services on one line per non-compliant interface.

The data I have looks something like this:

```
net self interface1 {
    allow-service none
}
net self interface2 {
    allow-service none
}
net self interface3 {
    allow-service {
        icmp:any
    }
}
net self interface4 {
    allow-service {
        icmp:any
    }
}
net self interface5 {
    allow-service {
        icmp:any
        default
    }
}
net self interface6 {
    allow-service all
}
net self interface7 {
    allow-service {
        icmp:any
        8888:tcp
        9999:any
    }
}
net self interface8 {
    allow-service {
        icmp:any
        default
    }
}
net self interface9 {
    allow-service {
        https:any
        ssh:any
    icmp:any
    }
}
net self interface10 {
    allow-service {
        icmp:any
        default
    }
}
```

The output I wish to get is something like this:

```
interface5, default
interface6, all
interface8, default
interface9, https:any, ssh:any
interface10, default
```

Additional conditions:

- It must be a oneliner
- I can't use a bash script, but I can use bash commands
- It must end with an awk script

Pretty peculiar limitations, I know.

I started poking around a bit and found this to give me only the data in the allow service section, but it will be showing trailing "}" and I have not figured out how to save the interface name:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="net self [A-Za-z0-9_]+ {\n[ ]+";ORS="=";}{print;}'
```

Any help or push in the right direction is much appreciated!

/Patrik

Comment: the default10 is repeacted twice. Pls edit output

Comment: Thanks mate, much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `gawk`

```
awk -F" " -v RS="{|}|allow-service|\n"  '/(https|ssh):any|all|default/{printf "%s, %s",prev,$1;prev="";u=2} /net self/{prev=$3} /net self/&&u==2{u=0;printf "\n"}' file
```

output

```
interface5, default
interface6, all
interface8, default
interface9, https:any, ssh:any
interface10, default
```

breakdown

```
    -F" " 
    RS="{|}|allow-service|\n"  
   '/(https|ssh):any|all|default/{printf "%s, %s",prev,$1;prev="";u=2} # print the values and set u-used to 2
    /net self/{prev=$3} #store interface
    /net self/&&u==2{u=0;printf "\n"} #print tags in new-line
```

Comment: Never do `printf $<anything>` as it'll fail if/when `$<anything>` contains printf formatting characters. Always do `printf "%s", $<anything>` instead. @PatrikJ you asked a question and accepted the first answer you got within an hour of asking it. I'm not saying it's not the best possible answer in every way, but we'll never know since everyone else is skipping your question since you have already accepted an answer.